# Placing one actor on top of another java

Tags: java, android

I am creating a program that is a recreation of the old game Frogger. A key part of the game is when the frog jumps across logs and to the other side of a river. However, when I make the frog move from the road to a log, the frog is positioned under the image of log instead of on top of the log. How can I make it so that the frog image lies above the log image?

I don't have an onDraw() method, at least I didn't write one. This is for an assignment in my class and we use a program called Greenfoot4Sofia. I created a subclass of Actor called Log, and I just used an option on the program to set the image of the actor to an image of a log, similarly with the frog.

Comment: Can you post your `onDraw()` method?  I'm not very experienced with this sort of thing, but it sounds as if you just need to draw the logs first and then draw your frogger afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would [this](https://github.com/web-cat/sofia-micro) happen to be the source for the library you mentioned? Perhaps you could also add some code in regards to your problem and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Greenfoot is obviously not set up to make this sort of thing easy, but is intended for new programmers... curious.

So, I'm not familiar with Greenfoot, but looking over the [API docs](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/), I notice that `World` objects have a `setPaintOrder(Class...)` method.  Perhaps you can use that?   If you haven't already, I would make the log its own class that extends Actor, i.e.-

```
public class Log extends Actor {
    // whatever code you have for your log
}
```

and do the same for your frogger.

Then (maybe) you can call the `setPaintOrder()` method of your `World`, i.e.-

```
myWorld.setPaintOrder( Log.class, Frogger.class );
```

This is obviously not the kind of code you can copy/paste, but hopefully it will get you on the right path.  There will probably be other things you need to draw as well, so you can just create an array of Class to pass to `setPaintOrder`:

```
ArrayList<Class> paintOrderList = new ArrayList<Class>();
// add the things you need in the order you need them to paintOrderList
Class[] paintOrder = paintOrderList.toArray( new Class[ paintOrderList.size() ] );
myWorld.setPaintOrder( paintOrder );
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is unlikely to have helped.  Greenfoot4sofia is, as far as I can tell, a local system that is only in use at Virginia Tech.  It does not share its API with the primary Greenfoot package, but uses the code editor and visual programming environment from Greenfoot adapted for use with VT's own local API.